# How to filter cell list in VBA depending on the values present in other columns and displaying the cell list along with its description in a user form

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet say "Sheet1" like this

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | column 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 |  |  | item8 |  |
|  |  | Search |  |  |

values of cells under each column are populated using a cell List created like so

```
        With rng.Validation
            .Delete 
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:=columnValueLst
```

the columnValueLst is a comma separated string which is made up of the values of cells under a column in a different sheet say "Sheet2" followed by a hardcoded string like "Search". "Sheet2" is like so

| header1 | header1 desc | set1_id | header2 | header2 desc | set2_id | header3 | header3 desc | set3_id | header4 | header4 desc | set4_id | header5 | header5 desc | set5_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | desc1 | id1 | item3 | desc3 | id2 | item5 | desc5 | id3 | item7 | desc7 | id4 | item9 | desc9 | id5 |
| item2 | desc2 | id1 | item4 | desc4 | id2 | item6 | desc6 | id3 | item8 | desc8 | id4 | item10 | desc10 | id5 |

so for column 1 in "Sheet1" the cells have a dropdown list which has all the values present under "header1" in "Sheet2". similarly for all the other columns of "Sheet1". I have another sheet, "Sheet3" which maps items from one set to the items of another.

| set id | item value | related set id | related item value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | item1 | id3 | item6 |
| id1 | item2 | id4 | item7 |
| id3 | item5 | id5 | item10 |
| id4 | item8 | id3 | item5 |

the purpose of "Sheet3" is to help in filtering of the cell list in "Sheet1". for example, if in "Sheet1" at A2 I select item1 as the value of the cell, then for that row in column 3 (that is at C2) the drop down list should change to just having item6.

The first problem im facing is implementing if now I select item8 at D2 then the list at C2 needs to only contain values which are common to both item1 and item8. Selection of a value in every column should further apply filter to every cell list present in the row.

If the "Search" option is selected in a cell, a user form opens which shows the list of values. For example if "Sheet1" Is completely blank except for the top most row, and at C3 I select "Search" in the drop down then a user form must open that displays all the values in the columns header3 and header3 desc respectively in different. Selecting any row and clicking the button "add item" sets the cell value of C3 to the item present under the header3 column of the user form.

The second problem I'm facing is on how to display only the filtered list of values in the search form, for example if I select item5 in column3 of "Sheet1" then upon selecting search option in column5 of the same row should open a user form that only displays item10 and its desc10

Comment: Are you talking about [cascading drop down lists](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5301-excel-cascading-drop-down.html)?

Comment: Yes essentially, but in reference to the example in the link, instead of having just one category column there are multiple and the drop down list for each of those columns in a row change depending on which value is selected in either (and if there is an entry for that item in the second column of sheet3 ). for example if in a row, columns of 2 values are selected , they both have an entry in sheet3 and the value in the "related set id" is the same, then the new list for that set id column in sheet1 should be made up of the "related item value" which are common to both the values selected.